# get the environment from cap staging deploy or cap production deploy

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I have a task that runs on deployment of either staging or production. Ideally I would like to pass in some arguments to the task depending on whether I am deploying to production or staging.

These tasks are within `lib/capistrano/tasks/`.

Within the `.rake` file how can I access the environment so I can determine what I need to set as the flag.

I have no issues setting the flag just not sure how I can access the environment.

If anyone can help it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: When you say "environment" do you mean: Capistrano env (dev/stage/prod), Rails environment, Environment variables, Something else?

Comment: When I say environment I mean is it either staging or production when cap staging deploy is ran for example. In that case it would be staging but in my task id like to fetch that.

Comment: Is this a Capistrano task or a rake task Capistrano is invoking?

Comment: rake task cap is invoking in the deploy.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are invoking the Rake task, you should be able to set an environment variable based on the value of `fetch(:stage)`. For example, something like:

```
run "APP_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)} bundle exec rake my:task"
```

The above code is untested, but should be basically what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately not using Rails and its local dev which means setting an env variable for each would be problematic and knowing which one its set.

Comment: What do you mean by local dev?

Comment: Sorry what I mean is that each time I would want it to be either production or staging I would need to edit the environment variable on my local machine as that is where the capistrano tasks are ran.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear, so I'll restate what I understand to be your use case:

You are running `cap dev deploy` or `cap stage deploy` locally (how you usually use Capistrano), and on deploy, it runs a Rake task on the server. You want the Rake task to know whether it is on dev or stage.

Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Sorry the rake task is on my local machine as well.

Comment: Ah, so the Rake task is invoked by the Capistrano script and runs locally?

Comment: Yes that is the case.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I ended up doing `run_locally do
      execute "gulp --gulpfile config/gulpfile.js #{fetch(:stage)}-optimisation"
    end`